# How to get the data from database on current date automatic

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

i want to get the data from database on current date. when i open page then i see get the data of today current date. if i select the another date then i get the another date data from database here is live example of my concept http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php if you visit here then you understand my concept

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
 {
   //ajaxTime.php is called every second to get time from server
   var refreshId = setInterval(function()
 {
   $('#timeval').load('ajaxTime.php?randval='+ Math.random());
 }, 1000);

   //stop the clock when this button is clicked
   $("#stop").click(function()
 {
   clearInterval(refreshId);
 });
 });
</script>
<form action="ko.php" method="get">
From : <input type="text" name="d1" class="tcal" value="<?php echo date("m/d/Y"); ?>" /> 
<input type="submit" value="SHOW">
</form>

<table id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: center; width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<thead>
<tr>
            <tr  bgcolor="#F1EDC2">
    <td><font color='#2F4F4F'><h2> Draw Time</h2></font></td>
    <td><font color='#2F4F4F'><h2> Wining Number</h2></font></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php
    include('connect.php');
    if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1  = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=('Y-m-d H:i:s'); }; 
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date = :a");
    $result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
  ?>
<tr class="record">
            <tr  bgcolor="#EEF3E2">
    <td><font size=5><font color='#008B00'><?php echo $row['dt']; ?></font></td>
    <td><font size=5><font color='#008B00'><?php echo $row['wn']; ?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

if i change this line `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date = :a");`   into `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date <= :a");` then i get all dates data ... but i want only current date data automatic here is live example of my concept http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php i want like this 100%

Comment: Remove the hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: so what i add here if i remove this Y-m-d H:i:s @royal-bg

Comment: Remove just the hours, minutes and seconds, leave the year, month and date. It's simple logic. If you want to retrieve records from current date, but one is from the morning, second from noon, you should not compare by time. Just date

Comment: no don't see any changes after i remove this ... its working same like before... i want like this visit here http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php @RoyalBg

Comment: What is the type of `date` column

Comment: You're also missing the `date()` part around your data-format. In your else.

Comment: @JohnRuddell again see script `date =a");`

Comment: no you need `date = DATE(:a)` ....... this is a mysql date formatter that removes the timestamp so its just the dd/mm/yyyy --- it may make it a bit slower, but it would probably solve your issue

Comment: no man its can't work after changes i getting so many errors

Comment: where i add the cudate @david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the data type of your `date` column.

But date, timestamp, and datetime items are just a little tricky to use in `WHERE` statements. If you want to find all the rows on a particular date the best way to do it is with:

```
WHERE whatever
  AND `date` >= DATE(:a)
  AND `date` <  DATE(:a) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This gets all the `date` values starting at midnight on the day I mentioned, up until but not including midnight on the day after the day I mentioned.

You could also do this (or some equivalent)

```
WHERE whatever
  AND DATE(`date`) = DATE(:a)  /* slow! */
```

but it will prevent the use of an index to satisfy your query, making it slow.

Here's an essay I wrote offering some background.
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

Answer (score 0):

three points to consider:
1. if you just want the current date result then just use "=".
2.here we need to see what is the datatype of you date column in the birthday table.
if the datatype is datetime then add hh:mm:ss to the date, or if the datatype is just date then just use date.
3. if the date column is int and storing them in timestamp then convert date to microtime and use it.

SELECT * FROM `yourTable` WHERE CURDATE() >= STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m-%d-%Y') DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y')` defeats the use of any index on `date` to satisfy the query.

Comment: @user3406756 i want this did you visit here http://joomusic.info/joosilver.php my script is complete 80% like this just i want to get automatic current date data which are you see on my given link

Comment: @ollie-jones i want this did you visit here joomusic.info/joosilver.php my script is complete 80% like this just i want to get automatic current date data which are you see on my given link